# Random errors while compiling a large document with LuaLaTeX via Latexmk

Tags: luatex, latexmk, compilation-error

I'm working on a rather large (200 pages) document.

Once or twice a day, I get a compile error which references a line that does not exist in my code. That is, the line does exist, but the error references contents that are slightly different from what the file actually contains.

The last such error was:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.166 \subsecction
                {Max-Pooling}
```

Line 166 of file `experiments.tex` contains that exact line, but without the double `c` and the newline:

```latex
\subsection{Max-Pooling}
```

I'm using the continuous option of Latexmk. On failure, it automatically recompiles just fine after that error, without me having to change a file (!). If I clean the build dir and then rebuild, no such error occurs. I've configured Latexmk with a `$failure_cmd` that prints the tail of the log and so catched the eror, but I haven't been able to catch full the log.

This is not a showstopper for me since on a recompile the error always goes away: however it's quite disturbing. I'm at a loss as to how to provide more info.

I can't share the full document and wouldn't know how to provide a MWE for this issue, since it is not a deterministic error.

These are the [packages I've loaded](https://pastebin.com/umidb430). I've also mounted the `$out_dir` to a RAM drive. I am using the `book` class and LuaLaTeX/Latexmk, on Kubuntu, TeX Live package:

> texlive/cosmic,cosmic,now 2018.20180824-1 all TexLive

Comment: Are these reproducible errors? If so, can you post an MWE and the details of your work flow?

Comment: Are you sure that the line number refers to you main tex and not e.g to the toc file?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sadly, they are not reproducible, as I said above it happens maybe once or twice a day, and *goes away* (shrug) after recompiling.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, since I have no toc file :). Also, the line references a file I'm including, not the main tex file.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke I think you should reread my question. I've posted other questions with a MWE; in this case, the error is non deterministic and appears in a 200 page document. I'm quite sure this is a bug somewhere in the latexmk-lualatex toolchain, the issue is *how* to reproduce it. As I mentioned, `I'm at a loss as to how to provide more info.`

Comment: The newline in the error message is normal, tex always adds them after an unknown command. If you are using lualatex you shouldn't use `\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0}` in your document - that is a xelatex setting. And you should better use `backend=biber`. But beside this it is quite impossible to debug your problem.

Comment: I have seen this from time to time as well (I don't use *continuous compilation*) and always assumed that it was caused by starting the compilation and then - while TeX is processing the file - saving the file to the disk again with a (small) change. If this happens in a way that the bytes in the file are shifted close to the position TeX just read, then that could explain why TeX reads `\subsecction` where the file only has `\subsection`. Unfortunately, I know nothing about how TeX reads files, so I don't know if my made-up theory holds water.

Comment: My humble tip is cleverref. Even though its great, this package sometimes misbehaves too.

Comment: Well, maybe you have to check your RAM with some memory errors checker.

Comment: May be you saved a new version of the file, whilst latexmk was in the middle of a compliation run.  This can quite easily happen when in continuous compilation mode.

Comment: @AndrewSwann No, I'm quite sure I didn't, of the few times (4 or 5) I've encountered this error, the file wasn't even open.